# How do I find the limit $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{1}{1 - x} - \frac{3}{1 - x^3}$

Tags: limits

How do I calculate the following limit? $$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{1}{1 - x} - \frac{3}{1 - x^3}$$

I already transformed this into

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{(1-x)(1-x)(x+2)}{(1-x)(1-x^3)} = \frac{(1-x)(x+2)}{(1-x^3)}$$

but this still has zeroes up- and downstairs. L'Hospitals rule is not allowed. Any advice?

**EDIT**: Sorry, I was doing confused. There is a 3 in the second numerator.

**EDIT 2:** [Wolfram Alpha says the limit is $-1$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20x%20to%201%3a%201/%281-x%29%20-%203/%281-x%5E3%29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that $1-x^3=(1-x)(1+x+x^2)$, so
\begin{align*}
\frac1{1-x}-\frac3{1-x^3} &= \frac1{1-x}\left[1-\frac3{1+x+x^2}\right] = \frac1{1-x}\cdot\frac{1+x+x^2-3}{1+x+x^2} \\ &= \frac1{1-x}\cdot\frac{(x+2)(x-1)}{1+x+x^2} = 
\frac{x-1}{1-x}\cdot\frac{x+2}{1+x+x^2} = -\frac{x+2}{1+x+x^2}
\,.
\end{align*}
From this we see that $\lim\limits_{x\to 1} = -1$.

P.S. You have it from where you were if you use the factoring on my first line to simplify your fraction.

Comment: I edited my question, so your answer is no longer correct. Please see above.

Answer (score 3):

**Answer to the original question**

The limit doesn't exist: $(1 - x^3) = (1 - x)(1 + x^2 + x)$, therefore
$$\frac{1}{1 - x} - \frac{1}{1 - x^3} = \frac{1}{1 - x}\Big(1 - \frac{1}{1 + x^2 + x}\Big).$$From this you get $$\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{1}{1 - x}\Big(1 - \frac{1}{1 + x^2 + x}\Big) = \infty$$
$$\lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{1}{1 - x}\Big(1 - \frac{1}{1 + x^2 + x}\Big) = -\infty$$

**Answer to the edited question**
$$\frac{1}{1 - x} - \frac{3}{1 - x^3} = \frac{1}{1 - x}\Big(1 - \frac{3}{1 + x^2 + x}\Big) = \frac{1}{1 - x}\frac{1 + x^2 + x - 3}{1 + x^2 + x} = \frac{1}{1 - x}\frac{(x - 1)(x + 2)}{1 + x^2 + x} = \frac{-x - 2}{1 + x^2 + x} \to \frac{-3}{3} = -1$$

Comment: I edited my question, so your answer is no longer correct. Please see above.

Comment: I edited with the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\frac1{1-x}-\frac1{1-x^3}=\frac{1+x+x^2-1}{1-x^3}=\ldots\ldots$$

Since

$$a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\ldots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})\;,\;\;n\in\Bbb N$$

Comment: I edited my question, so your answer is no longer correct. Please see above.

Comment: I beg to difer: my answer is correct to the question you originaly posted, so your question *now* is incorrect...

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{1 - x} - \frac{1}{1 - x^3}=\frac1{1 - x} - \frac1{(1-x)(1+x+x^2)}$$
$$=\frac{1+x+x^2-1}{1-x^3}=\frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)(1+x+x^2)}$$

$$\implies \lim_{ x\to1^+}\frac{1}{1 - x} - \frac{1}{1 - x^3}=+\infty$$

$$\implies \lim_{ x\to1^-}\frac{1}{1 - x} - \frac{1}{1 - x^3}=-\infty$$

Comment: This is wrong, the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: @user01123581321345589144..., thanks for your input, rectified.

Comment: I edited my question, so your answer is no longer correct. Please see above.